# CSS animation - HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following code:

```css
/* Contact Form */

input[type=text],
[type=email],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #0563bb;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.contactform {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.contactform:hover {
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.column {
  float: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column,
  input[type=submit] {
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="contact">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="contactform">
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <div class="section-title">
          <h2><br/>Get In Touch</h2>
        </div>
        <p>Feel Free To Reach Out To Me Through This Form! </p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <form name="myform" action="thankyou.html" method="POST" novalidate>
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="first name" name="firstname" placeholder="Your First Name.." required>
            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your Last Name.." required>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email.." required>
            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Lets Collaborate.." style="height:170px" required></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I basically want to add an animation where I want to add an animation on the input fields. Basically, I want my expected output to be like this:

```css
* {
  --input-height: 3rem;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

.input-container input {
  height: var(--input-height);
  width: 80vw;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.input-container {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center start;
}

.input-container label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
  background-color: white;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.input-container input:focus~label {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  top: -0.6rem;
  padding: 0.2em;
  left: 0.5rem;
  color: rgb(0, 81, 255);
  background-color: white;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <form action="">
      <div class="input-container">
        <input type="text" name="" id="my-input">
        <label for="my-input">hello world</label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, when you click the input field the text shortens and gets aligned on top of the input field. I would like this but with the contact form I have above. How would I incorporate this code above into the contact form code I sent before? I tried using the same logic but got stuck since my code that I sent at the very top is a bit different than what I sent directly above. Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this task? Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: You show what you did alone, you show what you want to do but you dont show what you tried to get it

Comment: You are showing us the answer to a previous question. As @SKJ asks, what have you tried in order to incorporate the given solution into your code? I notice several things you have not done - altered the input/label order, put each pair into another container.... Please try and if you get stuck then put the updated code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use some code from webdevtrick.com and morioh.com, I changed the code to use vanilla JavaScript instead

```js
/** Code By Webdevtrick ( https://webdevtrick.com )  **/

const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

inputs.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener("focusin", (e) => {
    e.target.previousElementSibling.classList.add("active");
  });

  input.addEventListener("focusout", (e) => {
    e.target.previousElementSibling.classList.remove("active");
  });
});
```

```css
/** Code By Webdevtrick ( https://webdevtrick.com ) **/

* {
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-family: "Alegreya Sans SC", sans-serif;
}

body {
  color: white;
  background-color: #f05855;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

div.main {
  width: 700px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div.main div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px 0;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: #f05855;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out, font-size 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out, font-size 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.active {
  top: -25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 800;
  background-color: #f05855;
  color: white;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Code By Webdevtrick ( https://webdevtrick.com )-->
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>CSS Input Label Animation | Webdevtrick.com</title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans+SC&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <h1>CSS Label Animation</h1>
    <div>
      <label for="FirName">First Name</label>
      <input id="FirName" type="text" class="styl" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="LasName">Last Name</label>
      <input id="LasName" type="text" class="styl" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="Messag">Your Message</label>
      <input id="Messag" type="text" class="styl" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, I have modified your template with the animation.

```css
* {
  --input-height: 3rem;
}
.contactform {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.contactform:hover {
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.column {
  float: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

.input-container input {
  height: var(--input-height);
  width: 80vw;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.input-container {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center start;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  width:50%;
}

.input-container label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
  background-color: white;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;

}

.input-container input:focus~label {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  top: -0.6rem;
  padding: 0.2em;
  left: 0.5rem;
  color: rgb(0, 81, 255);
  background-color: white;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  z-index: 2;
  
}
input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #0563bb;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column,
  input[type=submit] {
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
</br></br>
  <section id="contact">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="contactform">
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <div class="section-title">
          <h2><br/>Get In Touch</h2>
        </div>
        <p>Feel Free To Reach Out To Me Through This Form! </p>
      </div>
  <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
    <form name="myform" action="thankyou.html" method="POST" novalidate>
      <div class="input-container">
     <input type="text" id="first name" name="firstname" required>
        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-container">
     <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" required>
         <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
      </div>
      
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: It does not work since there are problems in the output and it does not match with the contact form